Title: Issue with RemoteViews ProgressBar Updates in Notifications (SDK 31+)
In Android SDK 31 and above, I encountered an issue with updating RemoteViews in a notification. I use a custom RemoteViews layout containing three ProgressBar elements (A, B, and C). The layout is displayed using setCustomHeadsUpContentView(remoteView).
Before SDK 31, the notification updated smoothly even when I refreshed the progress bars more than 10 times per second. Specifically:

ProgressBar A reflects an ongoing task and updates its progress dynamically.
ProgressBars B and C are set to indeterminate=true, indicating a waiting state, and their animations loop seamlessly.

However, starting from SDK 31, when ProgressBar A is updated frequently, ProgressBars B and C's indeterminate animations keep resetting to their initial state with every update to the RemoteViews. This results in a jerky animation for B and C, making the indeterminate state appear interrupted.
Is there a way to update only ProgressBar A in the RemoteViews without affecting ProgressBars B and C, so that their indeterminate animations continue uninterrupted?
There were attempts identical to those described in the details of the problem.
